# Angular 1.5 directive boolean value not passed into scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

var HelloDirective = function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      list: "=",
      showValue: "="
    }, // use a new isolated scope
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: false,
    template: '<h3>List value is {{list}}</h3><br/>Raw value is [{{showValue}}] <br/><br/>showValue value is: <span ng-show="showValue">True</span><span ng-hide="showValue">False</span>'

  };
}

myApp.directive("helloDirective", HelloDirective);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Angular Directive';
  $scope.osList = "Original value";
  $scope.bv = true;
})
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!  Value is {{bv}}
  <p list="osList" showValue="bv" class="" hello-directive></p>
  </div>
```

Here is the output:

> Hello, Angular Directive! Value is true
>
> List value is Original value
>
> Raw value is []
>
> showValue value is: False

oList displays properly but showValue does not pass the boolean properly, what's wrong?  See this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mbaranski/guq2qyuc/12/

Answer (score 2):

It (the attribute) should be `show-value="bv"` and not `showValue="bv"`

Answer (score 2):

You should have attribute name in `kebab case`(hyphen separated case).

That would be taken care by directive Normalization process to make it `camelCase` while mapping to isolated scope properties.

```
showValue="bv"
```

should be

```
show-value="bv"
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pankajparkar/guq2qyuc/13/)

Comment: Angular's [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)  use the term `camelCase` but good answer altogether (_Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel)_)